# Activity or Fragment which is better way to use for performance and reliable?

Tags: android, performance

I'm new to android and i have developing an android app that is starting now. It is kinds of saveable user input information with specific Date/Time. And reviewable previous stored data to user. And also store some setting information.

This may be look simple but it will cost a lot of UI components. I recently learned Activity and Fragment and preferred to use one Main Activity class and the rests are will build with Fragments.

My understanding is, Fragment is corporate with Activity Life cycle and intend to use as reusable for other Activities.

But the thing that i want to know is as i mentioned in question,

1. Is that cost performance for using Activity per UI View ?
2. If using with Fragment for UI View, it may be more good in performance but reliability (such as : manually maintaining data states while rotation with Activity and Fragment each other, but if used Activity it will more less custom maintenance) is more sure for using Fragment ?

I want some advice of my question.

Comment: how is this a duplicate? this is specifically about performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this :

[Activities vs Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318518/android-activity-vs-fragmentactivity),

[Activities vs Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500438/activities-vs-fragment-implementation) and

[Activities vs Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478233/android-need-some-clarifications-of-fragments-vs-activities-and-views)

Hope this helps.

Comment: it more useful to me last link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478233/android-need-some-clarifications-of-fragments-vs-activities-and-views. But it is not recommended to which is better instead it saying Advantages. But now i can clearly decidable for using Activity and Fragment.