# Performance of Android Application based on Activity and Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

What would be the effect on android application if i use only **Activities instead of using Fragments** or any other Interface in my Application?

Basically am creating an application wherein i have separate login for Users as well as Administrator and a common login page for both. comparing their login data am redirecting them to their respective activities.

But i wonder what would be the **performance of the app** if i use only activities for their respective process.

Could someone suggest in short manner the performance difference between Activity and Fragment?

Comment: I dont think using activity instead of fragment will have an impact on performance, performance is usually more related to draw calls, inflater and findViewById calls mostly, a larger xml layout view tree will have slower drawing.

Comment: Most importantly, the usage depends upon requirement.You can't use `Activity` were we should use fragment and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You're comparing apples and oranges.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges) They are not interchangeable. You should use them regarding for what requirements you would mind.

Basically the performance would heavily depends on:

- How big your XML layout is.
- How much tasks are getting done in UI thread.
- How frequent you are switching between views.

It should be noted that, in some cases using fragments just worsen the performance, because essentially once you attach a fragment, you are combining view hierarchy of both (that of activity and that of fragment) trees into one tree, which result in having a big tree. Now issuing a `requestLayout()` would affect the whole tree.

[Dilemma: when to use Fragments vs Activities:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306091/dilemma-when-to-use-fragments-vs-activities)

Answer (score 0):

Since i cannot comment at the moment I will put this as an answer here.

You should have a look at the following [Activity or Fragment which is better way to use for performance and reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514478/activity-or-fragment-which-is-better-way-to-use-for-performance-and-reliable)
and also all the related topics. Then you might find your answer there.